# $Av=λv$ basis proof problems

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So the question asks: Let A be a $2\times 2$ matrix, and suppose that there exist scalars $λ_1,λ_2$ in$\mathbb{R}$ and nonzero vectors $v_1,v_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $Av_1=λ_1v_1, Av_2=λ_2v_2$, and $λ_1$ does not equal to $λ_2$.Prove that the vectors $v_1,v_2$ form a basis of $R^2$.

So so far I got:

As the eigenvector $v_1,v_2$ are corresponding to two different eigen values$λ_1,λ_2$ respectfully.

Therefore the eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent.

And since $v_1,v_2$ spans A in $\mathbb{R}$.

Hence,  $v_1,v_2$ forms a basis of $\mathbb{R}$.

Does this proof look right? Do I need to write a linear combination of $v_1,v_2$ to show they span A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establishing the following facts would suffice:

1. Different eigenvalues correspond to linearly independent vectors.
2. Any linearly independent list whose length is equal to dimension is a basis.

You need to explain why "Therefore the eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent." and "And since $v_1,v_2$ spans $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$"